# How to create gradient fill, transparent background, radial gradient in Actionscript?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript

I'm trying to create spinning rays in actionscript to use in my website.
Below is the rough idea of what I'm trying to create.
[image: this is what I'm trying to create]
Is it possible to create absolutely with 0 images. If no then can someone tell me how to create it with images?
Following is the actionscript code in which I couldn't figure out how to add gradient, transparent background and little radial gradient to create glow effect.

```
function CreateRays():Shape {
 var ray:Shape = new Shape();
 ray.graphics.beginFill(0xFF9900,.5);
 ray.graphics.lineStyle(1,0xFF9900,.5);
 ray.graphics.lineTo(600,-70);
 ray.graphics.lineTo(600,70);
 ray.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
 ray.graphics.endFill();
 return ray;
}
var sun:Shape = new Shape();
sun.graphics.beginFill(0xFF9900,1);
sun.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,1);
sun.graphics.endFill();
//edit this no to change the no of rays :-)
var SunaRays:Number=15;
var rayShapes = new Shape();
var SunGlow:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
for (var i:int = 1; i<=SunaRays; i++) {
 rayShapes=CreateRays();
 rayShapes.rotation=360/(SunaRays)*i;
 SunGlow.addChild(rayShapes);
}
SunGlow.addChild(sun);
addChild(SunGlow);
SunGlow.x=stage.stageWidth/2;
SunGlow.y=stage.stageHeight/2;
//you can change fps here
stage.frameRate=100;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rotateSun);
function rotateSun(e:Event):void {
 //you change speed here
 SunGlow.rotation+=.1;
}
```

If you paste above code in 1st frame of your scene with nothing on your scene, it will give you sweet rotating rays! ;)